# Build Linear Regression with dynamic inputs in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build a simple shiny app using a linear regression that allows the user to select both the independent and dependent variables that are used in the lm() function and eventually plot out a few charts as well. I am currently stuck on passing the inputs to the lm() function on the server side of shiny and being able to print out the summary of the regression. Can anyone assist me in where my logic/code is going wrong. Below is the code

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

RegData <- as.data.table(read.table("/home/r2uphp/ShinyApps/IRViews/RegData.tsv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))

ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel("Regression and Time Series Analysis"), 
  sidebarPanel(
    p("Select the inputs for the Dependent Variable"),
    selectInput(inputId = "DepVar", label = "Dependent Variables", multiple = FALSE, choices = list("AvgIR", "YYYYMM", "SumCount", "AvgLTV", "AvgGFEE", "AvgRTC", "Date")),
    p("Select the inputs for the Independent Variable"),
    selectInput(inputId = "IndVar", label = "Independent Variables", multiple = FALSE, choices = list( "SumCount", "AvgIR", "YYYYMM", "AvgLTV", "AvgGFEE", "AvgRTC", "Date"))
  ),
  mainPanel(
    verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "RegSum"),
    verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "IndPrint"),
    verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "DepPrint")
    #plotOutput("hist")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    lm1 <- reactive({lm(paste0(input$DepVar) ~ paste0(input$IndVar), data = RegData)})

    output$DepPrint <- renderPrint({input$DepVar})
    output$IndPrint <- renderPrint({input$IndVar})
    output$RegSum <- renderPrint({summary(lm1())})

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[This is the result of the shinyapp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PZDQ.png)

Here is a sample dataset that I am using:

```
     YYYYMM      AvgIR SumCount    AvgLTV     AvgGFEE   AvgRTC       Date
 1: 2015-10 0.04106781   180029 0.7531805 0.002424778 319.6837 2015-10-01
 2: 2015-11 0.04036154   160061 0.7380383 0.002722529 312.6314 2015-11-01
 3: 2015-12 0.04001407   145560 0.7392874 0.002425912 313.0351 2015-12-01
 4: 2016-01 0.04034078   147693 0.7396932 0.002600640 315.0238 2016-01-01
 5: 2016-02 0.04055688   142545 0.7345160 0.002449523 310.3950 2016-02-01
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just need to build your formula correctly. I'm not sure what you think `paste0` does, but here's a better way

```
lm1 <- reactive({lm(reformulate(input$IndVar, input$DepVar), data = RegData)})
```

The `reformulate()` command will build the correct formula for you (note that the independent variables come first in the function.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I am not sure why the regular format of the lm() function is not working as it would in other scripts. Do you mind explaining why the need to use reformulate here as opposed to the standard lm()? 

E.g. I used the lm() function in a few other scripts and it was able to provide me with the desired result for the following function:

lm2 = lm(AvgIR ~ Date + AvgGFEE + AvgLTV + SumCount + AvgRTC, data = subSD)

But in this case it requires the reformulate, which I don't quite understand why it is needed.

Comment: There's a big difference between a character value in R and a proper symbol. A formula is a collection of unevaluated symbols. It does not involved character values at all. If you want to build a formula from character values (which are what `input$IndVar` and `input$DepVar` return), you need to use a function like `reformulate()` or `as.formula()`.